# How to edit /etc/hosts file to open angularjs springboot project in specific website address

Tags: java, angularjs, linux, spring-boot, hosts

I have an angularJS application with springboot and it runs on 8090 port number with "index.htm" file. Like below ;

```
192.168.1.25:8090/index.htm
```

I just googled about the changing port and I did the change with 80 port number so I can open the web page with

```
192.168.1.25/index.htm
```

But, in google there are plenty of angular result and they tell me to change those settings with in angular.json file. I created a temporary angular project and did those with successfully. But, I could not figure out about the angularjs part. I checked the project and I could not find any file like angular.json. After that checking the springboot, I found this part of where I can open the web page with the above second URL address ;

```
192.168.1.25/index.htm
```

The code of Spring Boot part is below (There is where I can change the port number) :

Those ones did the trick by the way.

```
config.getMemberAttributeConfig().setStringAttribute(ServerService.MANAGEMENT_URL_PREFIX, ":80/index.htm");

config.getMemberAttributeConfig().setStringAttribute(ServerService.MANAGEMENT_URL_PREFIX, ":80");
```

After those steps, I can easily serve my angularjs app on 80 port and start to thinking about editing the /etc/hosts file on the server machine as :

```
192.168.1.25/index.htm xyz.com
```

I did reboot when I finished the editing part and I tried again to write xyz.com on firefox browser it does not go to my application.

I am still looking on the google and still could not find any solutions about this problem.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Is your project AngularJS or Angular? The angular.json file was introduced in Angular 2+ and does not have any built-in purpose in AngularJS

Comment: @JacobStamm My project is AngularJS but while I was searching the solution, I found lot of results about  the Angular which told me to edit angular.json file. That's why I wrote Angular in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Format for hosts file is

```
#<ip>            <hostname that resolve to the ip>
192.168.1.25     xyz.com

# or a list of names
192.168.1.25     xyz.com     myapp.xyz.com
```

You do not put any port numbers or path parts in it. This will obviously only work if you edit the hosts file on all the computers
you are indending to access the site **from** and not necessarily on the host running the application itself.

That being said, you should probably read on supported [Spring Boot properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server) because starting an application server on a specific port should be as easy as adding `application.properties` file in java resources with the following line:

```
server.port=80
```

Comment: I checked the server.port in properties file and it shows 80 port number. After editing the host file as you said,I write example.com on browser and it showed me this as below ;


{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://example.com/profile"
    }
  }
}

The browser does not show me the web page until I write example.com/index.htm. Are there any possibilities for just writing example.com to reach example.com/index.htm without using DNS server or etc ?

Comment: @mertakkartal - name your default file `index.html` (not `.htm`) and place it in the `src/main/resources/public/index.html` . The current version of Spring Boot should pick it up as the default landing page when you open `http://example.com/`.

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do in the application code that helps you to change 192.168.1.25 into example.com - you either buy a domain and cofigure the DNS servers of your provider - or do the DNS servers' job and manually update /etc/hosts files on all computers that want to visit your site.

Comment: I did (Changing server.port to 80, moving index.htm to public directory with new name as index.html) what you said above but after all the things when I wrote example.com in browser, it shows me this :

`; { "_links" : { "profile" : { "href" : "example.com/profile" } } }`

I could not open my page even writing the ip address of the server. But I also changed this part of code like this :

`config.getMemberAttributeConfig().setStringAttribute(ServerService.MANAGEMENT_URL_PREFIX, ":80");`

I went far away as example.com/index.htm right now with out DNS server or getting domain.